# Delete related records in yii2 - best practices

Tags: mysql, database, activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My database uses *MyISAM* engine under the hood, so I can't invoke the cascade delete action, because *MyISAM* doesn't support it. At the same time, I would like to delete related records in my yii2 application. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2: How to simultaneously delete related models data from data base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110462/yii2-how-to-simultaneously-delete-related-models-data-from-data-base)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** below solution will be working only if you use [ActiveRecord delete method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#delete()-detail).

You can use [beforeDelete](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeDelete()-detail) method and delete related records there - in this case you'll write code once and it will be executed each time you call `$model->delete()`.

Or you can add handler to [EVENT_BEFORE_DELETE](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#EVENT_BEFORE_DELETE-detail) event.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I think that first of all optimization depends on the database itself (correct indexes etc). As an option you can create stored procedure that deletes related records and call that procedure...

Comment: What about creating triggers?

Answer (score 2):

There are several options to address this issue.

1) Create a [trigger](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_delete.php) on DB side:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE DELETE ON table_name FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN    
   -- variable declarations    
   -- trigger code    
END;
```

2) Delete related records inside yii2 [beforeDelete](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeDelete()-detail) function:

```
public function beforeDelete() {
    if (!parent::beforeDelete()) {
        return false;
    }
    // ... custom code here ...
    return true;
}
```

Triggers are faster, and good at enforcing referential integrity, that's why I chose them.