# Yii2: How to simultaneously delete related models data from data base?

Tags: php, yii

I used to work on Yii and now I'm building a new project on Yii2.

On Yii there was the function beforeDelete() and afterDelete() which allowed me to add the code there and delete related rows from junction tables etc..

My question is: On Yii2, is there another way to do this through an event or the database its self(on delete event on indexes)? What is considered to be good practice for these procedures?

Thanks!

Comment: I read to fast... I think it's the best way to do it. The other solution is to add trigger in database to do the job but I don't thinks it's a good idea you may forget them if someday you want to change them or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's handled with foreign keys and cascade deletion. In this case you don't have to write any additional code in deletion event handlers.

But, for more complex situations you can use the same ActiveRecord event handlers `beforeDelete()` and `afterDelete()`. It's better to delete related records in `afterDelete()` event after deletion of main model.

**Official docs:**

- [beforeDelete()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeDelete%28%29-detail)
- [afterDelete()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterDelete%28%29-detail)

Comment: That is probably the best way to go it seems... Thanks!